# VBA Syntax Error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use an unbound textbox and button to search my ID column (`Barcode`) and list the record in a form.

The issue I'm having is that according to many examples it looks correct, but I'm new to VBA.

```
Private Sub searchbutton_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

DoCmd.OpenForm "Update"

Set rst = Forms!Update.Recordset.Clone

rst.FindFirst (Barcode) =  & Me.searchtext
Forms!Update.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark

DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

End Sub
```

The issue is with line `rst.FindFirst (Barcode) =  & Me.searchtext` and throws a syntax error, but no specifics.

I've also tried:

```
rst.FindFirst [Barcode] = Me.searchtext
rst.FindFirst "[Barcode] = " Me.searchtext
rst.FindFirst (Barcode) = " Me.searchtext
```

The `[Barcode]` lines throw:

> Run-time error '3464' Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

the Barcode field is ShortText as it needs to support my barcodes which as "000001".....

Comment: Same issue, barcode is shorttext as i needed to keep the begining 000's which are on the barcodes, sorry I forgot to add that

Comment: That did not, still a Syntax error

Comment: I left out a needed `&` character.  Should be this: `rst.FindFirst "[Barcode] = '" & Me.searchtext & "'"`

Comment: That seems to make my form disappear but no syntax error

Comment: And thats because the script is telling it to close, yep working great thank you.  pop it as an answer and ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `FindFirst` a string expression ...

```vb
'rst.FindFirst (Barcode) =  & Me.searchtext
rst.FindFirst "[Barcode] = '" & Me.searchtext & "'"
```

However, I'm not sure why the original code triggered a runtime error.  Giving `FindFirst` this ... `(Barcode) =  & Me.searchtext` ... should trigger a compile error.  I don't understand why you didn't get a compile error.  Make sure you have `Option Explicit` in the Declarations section of your code module.